# Javascript randomly not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a page I'm coding, and it's supposed to run this Javascript on every page load. The problem is, it seems to load completely randomly. Sometimes it runs, sometimes it just doesn't. Every reload seems totally random on whether it will work or not. This is very frustrating as I can't imagine it's an issue with the code at this point.

```js
function randombg() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0;
  var bigSize = ["url('http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-dsFg9OnYo5Q/T0hK7b0-xoI/AAAAAAAABL4/9_CPzXBCMfw/s800/animated%2520blue%2520stars.gif')",
    "url('https://background-tiles.com/overview/blue/patterns/large/1026.gif')",
    "url('https://78.media.tumblr.com/395d407e0762d7041cbe0197e3ea288c/tumblr_o3fxwiIAq61v8fqfeo1_540.gif')",
    "url('http://backgroundcheckall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/seamless-repeating-background-gif-12.gif')",
    "url('https://other00.deviantart.net/b3aa/o/2009/312/0/8/143009517_95116_animated_starfield_tile.gif')",
    "url('http://backgroundcheckall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/seamless-repeating-background-gif-10.gif')"
  ];
  document.getElementById("random").style.backgroundImage = bigSize[random];
  alert("Success");
}

window.onload = randombg;
window.onresize = randombg;
```

```css
#random {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300&text=banner1');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body onload="randombg">
  <div id="random"></div>

  <body>
```

This is taken from [this pen](https://codepen.io/omascaros/pen/CBapm), which works flawlessly. So I'm very confused as to why it's not working consistently for me.

I'm running Chrome (67.0.3396.99) in Windows 10 (1803), and this code is being run in the extension [Super Evil New Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-evil-new-tab/dhphmpoekpoecdbjeionimpiceigkeil), which has a section for HTML, CSS, and JS.

Thank you for any feedback or advice.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the extension seems to just stick the HTML into a body.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: Also (though I haven't coded a "load" handler like this in many many years), I'm pretty sure it should be `<body onload="randombg()">`

Comment: Try removing the body tag from your "html", that extension you mentioned just inserts a snippet into the existing body... you're possibly creating one too many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest, non-library-dependent way to fix inconsistent JavaScript initialization execution is to change `<body onload="randombg">` to just `<body>` and insert your JavaScript before your script tag like so:

```
<script src="path/to/your/js/file/here.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="random"></div>
</body>
```

And then in your JavaScript file, instead of using `window.onload = ...`, do:

```
// This method of attaching a function to a DOM event allows for more flexibility down the line.
window.addEventListener('load', randombg);

window.addEventListener('resize', randombg);
```

If you use this `addEventListener` way, if you choose to do more than just `randombg` on `load` and `resize` events, you could just do

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    randombg();
    // more code to perform on load here...
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    randombg();
    // more code to perform on window resize here...
});
```

Comment: I'll try this, but as @JayB pointed out, the extension is sticking the HTML into a <body>. I can't work around that, can I?

Comment: After playing with the browser extension myself, I noticed that it sticks JavaScript code inside of a `<script>` tag in a `<head>` tag inside of an `<iframe>`. This, for some reason, does not play nicely with `window.addEventListener('load', ...)`. However, I was able to make it work by simply running the code inside the `'load'` event handler directly on the global scope (outside of any handler function), and then doing `window.addEventListener('resize', ...)` for the resizing code.

Comment: Thank you for going through all that trouble. I'm not quite an expert on JS yet; so are you telling me to move the JS into the HTML, or am I not understanding you completely?

Comment: Not a problem! Just stick your JS inside the `Custom JavaScript` box, execute whatever you want to execute without sticking it inside the `<body onload=...>` tag, use a simple `<body>...</body>` tag for your HTML, and inside your JS use `window.addEventListener('resize', randombg);` for your resize code.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, I can't believe I was one three lines away from the answer.